# Node/TS-node crashing without a stack trace

Tags: node.js, typeorm, ts-node

I'm having an issue where a node project suddenly started crashing on launch with merely a `error Command failed with exit code 1.` The project is ApolloServer/Express based.

Start script: `ts-node src/app.ts`

- Running via ts-node crashes right after express().listen() logs "Server is starting" message
- Running through pm2 will cause a crash loop before randomly working
- Running via ts-node-dev works (Uses the same version of ts-node)
- Running on Windows 10 works

ts-node: "9.1.1"

ts-node-dev: "1.1.8"

typescript: "4.4.4"

node: "14.13.1"

yarn: "1.22.17"

Debian: 9.13

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue. Have you resolved it yet?